# How play music as Document directory in swift?

Tags: swift, document, audio-player

I can't read the file in the document

Get file in the document and show on the table view 
if file as mp3 music did select on row play music

```
func loadMusic()
{
    let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
    let files = FileManager().enumerator(atPath: documentsPath)

    var myFiles:[String] = []
    while let file: AnyObject = files?.nextObject() as AnyObject? {
        myFiles.append(file as! String)
        print(file)
    }
```

I use this function to see log name of file in document but I can't see in my app.

Answer (score 0):

its better that you create array from your local media and then show this array in tableView.
use this method for create array from local media

```
 var localMedia = [String]() // array for save local audio names
 let directory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    if let urlArray = try? FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: directory,
                                                                   includingPropertiesForKeys: [.contentModificationDateKey],
                                                                   options:.skipsHiddenFiles) {


        localMedia = urlArray.map { url in
            (url.lastPathComponent, (try? url.resourceValues(forKeys: [.contentModificationDateKey]))?.contentModificationDate ?? Date.distantPast)
            }.sorted(by: { $0.1 > $1.1 }).map { $0.0 }

        print("media = \(localMedia)")
```

Comment: media = ["music", "Sina Sarlak - Donya.mp3", "Ehaam - Khoda Negahdar - MP3 320.mp3", "Reza Bahram - Gole Eshgh - MP3 320.mp3"]
This Log out put
How Call in table view and play the music?

Comment: use array of localMedia for handle tableView and put your player code inside didSelectRow of your tableView